# GraphViz Powershell Graph command

Tags: powershell, graphviz

Using Powershell.

The following works as expected

```
graph "myGraph" {
    edge start,middle,end        
}
```

However, the following does not work - how should I pass $st variable?

```
$st='edge start,middle,end'
graph "myGraph" {
    $st
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using [PSGraph](http://psgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/about/) which is all about piping commands together. `edge` is one of the commands, if you simply include it in a variable together with its parameters, it won't get executed.

However, if you extract the command from the variable, like [demonstrated in the examples](http://psgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Command-Edge/), you should be fine:

```
$st = @('start','middle','end')
graph "myGraph" {
    edge $st
}
```

Comment: My question is about using the string variable (which includes the 'edge' keyword) and be able to pass it in a scriptblock; I was able to do it via [Scriptblock]::Create($st)  and it works.  But in my case $st is a string array with a list of statements - and it fails i.e. graph is unable to covert it to the DOT syntax.